# How to write a struct to a file using write()

Tags: c

1) I have a struct and need to write it to a file using the write() system call, NOT fwrite(). Is this possible?

2) After writing the structure to the file, I need to read another file, and write it to end of the file the structure is now written in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any concerns whatsoever for the portability of structure image being written (endianness of members, structure packing, etc)? If not, it is trivial, if so, you should mention it, and if that question isn't understood, you may wish to understand the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will write your structure to a file.

```
int fd = open(file, O_WRONLY);
struct my_struct a;

write(output, &a, sizeof(struct my_struct));
```

For the other file, simply open it, read it's content in a loop, and write it to the previous.

```
int fd2 = open(otherfile, O_RDONLY);
int readret;
char buf[4096];

while ((readret = read(fd2, buf, sizeof(buf) != 0) {
  write(fd, buf, readret); 
}
```

remember to test every write/read result, (as mention in the comment), and handle those errors.

Comment: You *always* should test the result of `write`

Comment: The output of `write()` is important to check, as it failing should signal your program to poke the user. While not as common as the days of old where 360K floppies filled up quickly (thus, _nothing_ in memory could be written unless the user did something), small flash drives do present the same scenario. The most common cause of `write()` failing isn't an unstable system, just a full drive - which users appreciate knowing about :)

Comment: Alright I got the first part. But for the second part, what are "readret" and "buf"?

Comment: I updated my answer to explicit `readret` and `buf` declarations. `readret` is the number of characters read, `buf` the buffer where those are stored.

Comment: `write(output, &a, sizeof(struct my_struct));` Here `output` is `fd` or anything else. As getting garbage data into file for my case

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about writing your structure in binary, then yes.  The function usage as described in K&R is:

```
int n_written = write( int fd, char *buf, int n );
```

So you would have:

```
struct mystruct s;
write( fd, (char*)&s, sizeof(s) );
```

If you wish to serialize the struct in text, you will want to use `sprintf` or similar to construct a formatted string and then write that out to the file.

Now, you want to read in another file and write that out to the file you just dumped the struct into.  Just use `read` and `write` to move chunks of data at a time.  A reasonable practise is to move chunks that are a multiple of the disk sector size (traditionally 512 bytes, but these days you might want to take something like 4096 for generality).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have declared

```
struct somestruct_st mydata;
```

you can write it with

```
ssize_t cnt = write (yourfd, &mydata, sizeof(mydata));
if (cnt != sizeof(mydata)) {
   // handle that case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write and fwrite just work the same way the only difference is that write uses a file destriptor (fd), where fwrite uses a FILE *

Comment: Not exactly; `fwrite` is buffering, but not `write` (except in the kernel).